# What contract to query for getting user's staking rewards info for Pancakeswap Auto CAKE pool?

Tags: smartcontracts, pool, cryptocurrency, binance-smart-chain

I managed already to write code interacting with Auto CAKE pool contract in order to get user balance. This can be done by interacting with bsc smart contract 0xa80240Eb5d7E05d3F250cF000eEc0891d00b51CC and calling userInfo function.

Hoewever, this function does not return the current balance but it returns the " cakeAtLastUserAction", which is the total number of CAKE deposited in this contract by the user. It doesn't include the CAKE rewards generated in-between.

What contract should be queried to get the number of CAKE rewards generated for a user with the Pancakeswap AutoCAKE pool?

Comment: Same issue. Aside from `cakeAtLastUserAction`, there's also `shares`. I guess those shares would need to be part of some calculation to get to the Auto Cake reward. Also looked into the contract code - but can't seem to find a way to do it.